# Trying to rewrite "/" root to a relative root and not a global root. Use .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have a webpage, `http://site.com/directory/sub-directory/index.html`

In that webpage, I have an image that looks like this,`<img src="/images/picture.jpg" />`

The webpage is going to look for that image in `http://site.com/images/`

I'd like it to look for that image in `http://site.com/directory/sub-directory/images/`

The easy solution is just to get rid of the leading `/` in the `src` tag.  So it would be, `<img src="images/picture.jpg" />`.

But, is there any way I can keep that leading `/` sign and have this webpage and **any** other webpage inside the `/sub-directory/` folder think a leading `/` sign (or root) is really `http://site.com/directory/sub-directory/` and not `http://site.com`?

I'd imagine I'm (or looking for a solution that lets me) editing my .htaccess file that is located in `http://site.com/directory/sub-directory/`.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility there would be to use the referrer, as that would be the only context sent with a request.

If you made a regex on `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}`, matching the initial path to the image, then use the `%1..` expansions in the `RewriteRule` that might suffice.

Either that or pump the image requests through a PHP process to handle it.

Personally, I would just keep a root `/images/` directory with subpaths within that to respective images.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're suggesting an actual solution or a direction to go to find a solution. Keeping a root /images/ folder is not what I want to do, I'd rather it think my root was my sub-directory, while I'm in that specific sub-directory.  So when I call '/images/picture.jpg', it's really looking at http://site.com/directory/sub-directory/images/picture.jpg

Comment: @Mike B.: Yes I understand that, looking at `http://www.site.com/dir/sub/page.html` and getting images referenced as `images/picture.jpg` from `http://www.site.com/dir/sub/images/picture.jpg`.  My answer was intended to be a direction to look at, if you're familiar with `RewriteCond` usage.  The last sentence, which you appear to have focussed on, was what I would do instead, not my answer.

Comment: @Mike B.: See -  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Gotcha.  Sorry for the confusion. If it helps, I'm not familiar enough with .htaccess syntax enough to start hacking up a RewriteCond statement.  Any chance you could provide me one to be used generally?

Comment: @Mike B.: Something along the lines of `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} www.site.com(/.+)/$` followed by `RewriteRule ^/images/(.+)$ %1/images/$1 [L]`.  Untested, so might need playing with a bit.  This assumes your image sources are `/images/picture.jpg` type, ie. absolute to base.